# Partitioning table based on first letter of a varchar field

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a massive table (over 1B records) that have a specific requirement for table partitioning:

**(1) Is it possible to partition a table in Postgres based on the first character of a varchar field?**

*For example:*

For the following 3 records:

```
a-blah
a-blah2
b-blah
```

`a-blah` and `a-blah2` would go in the "A" partition, `b-blah` would go into the "B" partition.

**(2) If the above is not possible with Postgres, what is a good way to evenly partition a large growing table?** (without partitioning by create date -- since that is not something these records have).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an expression in the `partition by` clause, e.g.:

```
create table my_table(name text)
partition by list (left(name, 1));

create table my_table_a
partition of my_table
for values in ('a');

create table my_table_b
partition of my_table
for values in ('b');
```

Results:

```
insert into my_table 
values
    ('abba'), ('alfa'), ('beta');

select 'a' as partition, name from my_table_a
union all
select 'b' as partition, name from my_table_b;

 partition | name 
-----------+------
 a         | abba
 a         | alfa
 b         | beta
(3 rows)
```

If the partitioning should be case insensitive you might use

```
create table my_table(name text)
partition by list (lower(left(name, 1)));
```

Read in the documentation:

- [Table Partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html)
- [CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html)