# MySQL partitioning based on the first letter of varchar field

Tags: mysql, partitioning, partition, database-partitioning

I have a very similar problem asked in [Partitioning table based on first letter of a varchar field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47984591/partitioning-table-based-on-first-letter-of-a-varchar-field) for Postgres, however, I want to do this in mysql 5.7.

Is it possible to partition a table in MySQL based on the first character of a varchar field?

I have a vertical table with the format:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `field_value` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

The size of this table is more than 100M records.

Most of the select queries we use, specify the `field_name` to search for. What I want to do is divide the table based on `field_name`.

So that when we have a query like `field_name='email'` and `field_value='xyz@mail.com'` then the query simply searches in the partition that contains all the emails and skip rest of the partitions.

The `field_name` is not a comprehensive list, hence, I won't be able to use list partitioning. Key partitioning also might be tough to use, because I don't want to include the id in the partitioning and key partitioning requires primary key to be included.

For example:

For the following 3 records:

```
a-blah
a-blah2
b-blah
```

`a-blah` and `a-blah2` would go in the **A** partition, `b-blah` would go into the **B** partition.

(2) If the above is not possible with MySQL, what is a good way to evenly partition a large growing vertical table?

Comment: How large do you expect this table to become, and have you experimented with something simpler such as just putting an index on the `field_name`?

Comment: Yes, there is already an index on `field_name` and the data is expected to double in the next year.

Comment: Partitioning will, in general, not speed up your queries. While there are some queries that may profit (e.g. range scans on the partition key that cannot use the index, but do a full table scan - then `all` can be just the partition; this is usually someting date-related), in most cases it is a maintainance tool (to e.g truncate old data fast, or handling *large* tables where you get filesize problems) . Specifically, looking up data with `field_value='xyz@mail.com'` will get (a tiny bit) slower, due to the overhead of checking in which partition this entry is in.

Comment: It is not possible _and it will not speed up queries_.  Instead, have a suitable index.

Comment: Rule of thumb:  The most common letter occurs 10% of the time.  That is, one partition will hold 10% of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> field_name='email' and field_value='xyz@mail.com'

So, your *real* problem is the EAV schema design.  It has lots of inefficiencies, and Partitioning, especially the way you suggest will not help performance.

WordPress is a common example of EAV, but it can be helped a little by improving the indexes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta

More generically:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Techniques to help with EAV:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav

There are only 4 cases where Partitioning helps performance; it does not sound like your case fits:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint